# Salary Calculation Function in JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, html, function

From the input on the HTML, the user inputs the employee name and a number of hours they worked. From here on the submit button it takes the information and stores it in the variables so that I can calculate how much their pay was. Now with this also comes the overtime pay. I thought this was on the right track but whenever I go back to my HTML it displays "undefined". Any suggestions?

```
//Global Variables
var employeeName = document.getElementById("name").value;
var employeeHours = document.getElementById("hours").value;



function paySalary() {
    if (employeeHours <= 40) {
      var regtime = 11.00 * employeeHours;
      var overtime = 0.00;
      var salary = regtime;
    } else if (employeeHours > 40) {
       var regtime = (11.00 * 40);
       var overtime = ((11.00 * 1.5) * (employeeHours - 40));
       var salary = (regtime + overtime);
    }
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Employee Name: " + employeeName + " | Employee Gross Pay: " + salary;
}

//Event Listener to Submit
var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
if (submitButton.addEventListener) {
    submitButton.addEventListener("click", paySalary, false);
} else if (submitButton.attachEvent) {
    submitButton.attachEvent("onclick", paySalary);
}
```

[Screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHBiB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the scope of your salary variable, it's defined inside the if-else block. Make your salary variable accessible to document.getElementById() by declaring it in your function like this:

```html
<html>
<script>

function paySalary() {
    var employeeName = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var employeeHours = document.getElementById("hours").value;

    if (employeeHours <= 40) {
      var regtime = 11.00 * employeeHours;
      var overtime = 0.00;
      var salary = regtime;
    } else if (employeeHours > 40) {
       var regtime = (11.00 * 40);
       var overtime = ((11.00 * 1.5) * (employeeHours - 40));
       var salary = (regtime + overtime);
    }
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "Employee Name: " + employeeName;
    document.getElementById("pay").innerHTML = "Employee Gross Pay: " + salary;
}

</script>

<body>
<input id="name" value="Kamesh Dashora"></input>
<input id="hours" value=40></input>
<br>
<span id="pay">0</span>
<br>
<button id="submit" onclick="paySalary()">Submit</button>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this and I got it to work for a whole second and then it has done nothing but give me a 0 value. I believe this is because of my: `var employeeName = document.getElementById("name").value;
var employeeHours = document.getElementById("hours").value;` Is there anything you suggest? I don't believe my input value is properly going to my javascript on the onclick

Comment: Do it like this, this works perfectly. The problem was that you were declaring  global variables employeeName and employeeHours that fire on page load only i.e. only one time initialization. So after you call the function it will not be initialized again if variables are global. Hence do it like this.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to figure this out for so long! :)